# How does this update a component without using an actionListener?

Tags: java, actionlistener, paintcomponent

[Code in Question](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/IconDemoProject/src/components/IconDemoApp.java)

There isn't an actionListener for the image thumbnails, yet when clicked they update the image.

[From this webpage.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#example)

Edit:  I am currently importing images using JFileChooser and then creating a thumbnail and displaying the full image in a similar way to this, although not using ImageIcons. But would like to use this method so when I add an image it adds to the list and allows me to click the thumbnail to show that image.

However mine using actionListeners to change when something is pressed but this doesn't and can't understand the code where it does.

Thanks

Edit2:

Regarding the repaint option:

### I have a class which extends component which then calls a repaint function.

```
public class Image extends Component {

private BufferedImage img;

//Print Image
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

### I then have a class with all my Swing components which call methods from other classes.

```
Image importedImage = new Image(loadimageone.openFile());
Image scaledImage = new Image();
// Save image in Buffered Image array
images.add(importedImage.getImg());
// Display image
imagePanel.removeAll();
imagePanel.add(importedImage);
imagePanel.revalidate();
imagePanel.repaint();
previewPanel.add(scaledImage);
previewPanel.revalidate();
previewPanel.repaint();
```

If I remove the revalidate or repaint it wont' update the image on the screen.

**Edit 3:**

This is the code on how I implemented the dynamic buttons:

```
//Create thumbnail
    private void createThumbnail(ImpImage image){
        Algorithms a = new Algorithms();
        ImpImage thumb = new ImpImage();
        //Create Thumbnail
        thumb.setImg(a.shrinkImage(image.getImg(), 75, 75));
        //Create ImageIcon
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(thumb.getImg());
        //Create JButton
        JButton iconButton = new JButton(icon); 
        //Create ActionListener
        iconButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bottomBarLabel.setText("Clicked");
                imagePanel.removeAll();
                imagePanel.add(images.get(position)); //Needs Fixing
                imagePanel.revalidate();
            }
        });
        //Add to previewPanel
        previewPanel.add(iconButton);
        previewPanel.revalidate();
        previewPanel.repaint();
    }
```

Comment: Please put the minimal relevant piece of code that you tried or need help with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it uses ThumbnailAction instead which extends AbstractAction (at the very bottom of the code). Swing components can use Actions instead of ActionListeners. The advantage of Actions is that buttons can share an Action and they will automatically use the same key-bindings etc.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html

**EDIT**: I have added some code demonstrating that you do not need to explicitly repaint(). Give it a try.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    final JLabel iconLabel = new JLabel();
    JButton button = new JButton("Put Image");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                try {
                    iconLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(fc.getSelectedFile())));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    panel.add(iconLabel);
    panel.add(button);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

**EDIT 2** (There is no Edit 2)

**EDIT 3**: Try this

```
public class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel imagePanel;
    private Image image;

    public MyActionListener(JPanel imagePanel, Image image) {
        this.imagePanel = imagePanel;
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Clicked");
        imagePanel.removeAll();
        imagePanel.add(image); //Needs Fixing
        imagePanel.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah great, that's it. There doesn't seem to be a paint function to update the label though, how does it show the new image?

Comment: @user2916314 `photographLabel.setIcon(displayPhoto);` at the very end triggers the repaint. Swing components often refresh automatically when you modify them.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I have updated the original post showing my code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll give it a try. Although I don't use Icons to show the image, I add it straight to a Jpanel. Is this the reason why it isn't working?

Comment: @user2916314 Yes, when you add a new Component to your layout, you have to revalidate. EDIT: For this reason, I advise against changing your GUI unless necessary. Updating a Component rather than adding a new one is more Model-View-Controller-y.

Comment: Thanks again, It think I should be using Icons then. I import images which are updated on the screen as they are added, along with a thumbnail at the bottom showing what items have been added; which I want to make clickable like in the first program I linked. I also have a List which contain the imported images which people can cycle through which will update the Icon as well.

Comment: @user2916314 If you're adding thumbnails, you may find it appropriate to add Components. One way around this would be to use a JList of your images and use a custom renderer, but it might just be better to add new components and revalidate.

Comment: Ok, I have manage to get my thumbnails working and they're clickable. However I having an issue in changing the image when their respective thumbnail is clicked. 
The way I have implemented this is: 1) Open image, 2) Add image to List, 3)Create a thumbnail of image -> add to ImageIcon -> add to Jbutton -> add to component w/ actionListener. 
The issue is I don't store the buttons in a list so it doesn't know what number its respective image is in the List. Is there a way for me to see what number component it is in JFrame? Or is there something else I can try? Thanks

Comment: @user2916314 I would have to see your code to know exactly what to recommend, but one possible solution would be to store a reference to the Image in your ActionListener. Then you can get the original Image on click.

Comment: Actually that was my initial plan, but failed horribly; I tried storing the index in the TextTipTool, which involved converting to a string and back, then couldn't read it in the ActionListener.

I've update the Original Post showing the code I have. It takes in a class which contains a BufferedImage that it makes into a thumbnail then adds to a component at the bottom of the UI. I trying to make position the right index number. Many Thanks.

Comment: @user2916314 I've put more code in my answer. If you need more help, you should start another topic.